# JsonCpp: How to get en empty object in a Json::Value?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I have an external library that receive a `Json::Value` as a parameter. It will then output a string containing a JSON structure with my passed `Json::Value` somewhere in that structure.

I'm trying to put an empty object `{}` in that `Json::Value` with [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Ultimately I'm trying to parse that empty JSON object from a `std::string` that contain `"{}"` and I need that in a `Json::Value`.

When I declare a `Json::Value` and do nothing with it and pass it to my library, I get `NULL` instead of `{}`...

Comment: Where exactly does it fail for you (the usual parsing of the json)? You didn't mention your output.

Comment: @ Alex M. Updated my question maybe it will help. Nothing fail I'm just wondering how to load my string (containing an empty object `{}`) in a Json::Value...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample:

```
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse("{}", root);
assert(root != Json::nullValue);
std::string someStr = Json::FastWriter().write(root);
assert(someStr == "{}\n");
```

All of the assertions pass, so the parsed object doesn't have a null value and when you write it back to string you get your empty object `"{}"` back. Did this not work for you?

Comment: Just before you posted your answer I found [this article](http://garajeando.blogspot.ca/2011/06/we-are-using-json-javascript-object.html) Which is about the same,,, Finally it's the library that I call who convert empty JSON `{}`to `NULL`. Accepting as answer because it's what I wanted to know originallly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It may be helpful for someone:
In current ver. that i'm using - 1.8.2, you can get empty Object like this:

```
Json::Value root;
root = Json::objectValue;
```

Comment: I had a need for a similar operation. I had an existing root, which needed a named, empty object (dynamically, there were cases when the populating data was not available). For legacy reasons, a named null child would not have cut it. Because of the above answer, I went from all kinds of silliness to this sweet, elegant code: `Json::Value& sub_root = root["name"] = Json::objectValue;` Then I can fill the sub_root or leave it empty and the receiver will do the right thing. This was a conversion from ad-hoc JSON construction to using JSONcpp. Very happy. The above answer should be the accepted.